# Subplot breaks down when additional x-axis title is added

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, subplot

I have this data frame:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","dfgh","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","gh","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22 <- data.frame(gene_symbol, panel, ASDDA, ASDDb, ASDDAf, ASDDAf1, ASDDAf2, 
                            ASDDAf3, ASDDAf4, ASDDAf5, ASDDA1, ASDDb1, ASDDAf1, ASDDAf11,
                            ASDDAf21, ASDDAf31, ASDDAf41, ASDDAf51)
```

And I create 6 heatmaps with:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
HG3 <- split(Gene_states22[,1:15], Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4 <- HG4[,-5]
HG5 <- split(HG4, HG4$panel)
p <- list()
for(i in 1:as.numeric(length(HG5))){
  p[[i]] <- ggplotly(
    ggplot(HG5[[i]], 
           aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                colour = "grey50") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
      labs(title = "Heatmap", subtitle = names(HG5[i]), 
           x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value")+
      guides(fill=FALSE)+
      theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", size = 14, face = "bold"), 
            axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", size = 16, 
                                      face = "bold", color = "black"), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(family = "sans serif", size = 11),
            axis.text.y= element_text(family = "sans serif", size = 11),
            axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 10,hjust = 10),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
            panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
            strip.placement = "outside")
  )%>%
    layout(autosize = F, width=1350, height=600,
           hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                             font = list(family = "sans serif", size = 9, color = "black"))) 
}
```

Then I combine them to one with `subplot()`

```
subplot(p) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "sample"), 
         xaxis=list(title=names(HG5[1])),
         margin = list(l = 200, b = -10, t =-10), 
         xaxis2 = list(title = names(HG5[2])), 
         xaxis3 = list(title = names(HG5[3])), 
         xaxis4 = list(title = names(HG5[4])),
         xaxis5 = list(title = names(HG5[5])),
         xaxis6 = list(title = names(HG5[6])))
```

As you can see in the picture below when I create 6 heatmaps as the different types of `panel` the plot is displayed correctly.

[image]

The problem is that this number of `panel` types may vary from 1 to 8 so I would like to give 8 axis titles by default into my subplot. But when I put an additional title by:

```
subplot(p)%>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "sample"),
         xaxis=list(title=names(HG5[1])),
         margin = list(l = 200, b = -10, t =-10), 
         xaxis2 = list(title = names(HG5[2])), 
         xaxis3 = list(title = names(HG5[3])), 
         xaxis4 = list(title = names(HG5[4])),
         xaxis5 = list(title = names(HG5[5])),
         xaxis6 = list(title = names(HG5[6])),
         xaxis7 = list(title = names(HG5[7])))
```

The sublot is not displayed properly as it is like another plot is stuck on the original.
[image]

I cannot figure out why this is happening and of course I would be open in an alternative solution from which I selected regarding the xaxes titles.

Comment: Would faceting by panel (rather than make separate plots for each panel) be useful in your case? You'd avoid all the manual labelling that way.

Comment: could you make a solution on this? I just started using ggplot2 and Im not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, if you wish to split your data frame based on the value of one (or two) variable, & plot each slice as a separate plot, faceting is a common way to achieve the look.

See if the following code works for you. I skipped some of the theme specifications in the question's example, as they aren't crucial to the question:

```
pp <- ggplot(HG4, 
       aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
            colour = "grey50") + 
  facet_grid(~panel, scales = "free") +

  # it looks like you have more colours than values here.
  # I recommend using a named vector in this case, so that 
  # the same value always maps to the same colour.
  # e.g. values = c("DF" = "white", "low" = "red", ...)
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +

  labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")

ggplotly(pp,
         width = 1350, height = 600) %>%
  # note: specifying width / height in layout() has been deprecated
  # in recent versions of plotly. when I used it that way, I got
  # a warning to specify it within ggplotly() instead.
  layout(autosize = F, 
         hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                           font = list(family = "sans serif", size = 9, color = "black")))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: What are these numbers in the x-axis?

Comment: Your solution is useful thanks. I will accept it if something better does nor come up. I have one question. Can I move this grey box below the heatmap?